# How to Correct This SQL CODE?

Tags: sql-server

This is the question using AdvetureWorks2012.

> Create a VIEW dbo.vw_Commissions to display the commissions earned last
>   year by all sales employees. Round the result set to two decimal places and do not include any salesperson who did not earn a commission. Include the
>   salesperson name, the commission earned, and the job title. Concatenate the
>   salesperson first and last names.

This code is not working for me. What am I screwing up?

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Commissions
AS
    SELECT  
        Sales.SalesPerson.SalesLastYear,
        Person.Person.LastName,
        Person.Person.FirstName,
        HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle
    FROM 
        Sales.SalesPerson
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       Sales.SalesPerson ON Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID = Person.Person.BusinessEntityID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       Person.Person ON Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = HumanResources.Employee.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Please define, as specifically as you can, "not working."

Comment: Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_Commissions, Line 5
The objects "Sales.SalesPerson" and "Sales.SalesPerson" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: You didn't join to `HumanResources.Employee`.

Comment: but how do I do that?

Comment: *This is not working* is not a meaningful problem description.  In what **specific way** is it not working? Are you getting wrong results? An error message? Something else? You need to be specific and provide the details if you want our help.

Comment: This is just wasting our time

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your query.

1. The biggest problem is it is not answering the questions asked. You are selecting `SalesLastYear` whereas the question asks to calculate the Commissions.
2. You are not filtering SalesPersons which have not earned any commission.
3. You need this to run only for last year.
4. Concatenate the FirstName and LastName.

The error you are getting is because you are using `Sales.SalesPerson` twice in your query. You need to give them alias names. However, I don't think you need two instances of the same table in this query. Also to use `HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle` column in the select list, you need to include table `HumanResources.Employee` in the from list.